# Greek letters in uimenu label

Tags: matlab, special-characters, matlab-figure, menubar, matlab-gui

I'm trying to have a `uimenu` whose `'Label'` contains and displays both roman and greek letters.

I've tried :

```
uimenu(h,'Label','test with σ')                   % displays 'test with ?'
uimenu(h,'Label','test with \sigma')              % displays 'test with \sigma'
uimenu(h,'Label',['test with' char(963)])         % displays 'test with'
uimenu(h,'Label','<html>test with σ</html>')      % displays 'test with ?'
uimenu(h,'Label','<html>test with \sigma</html>') % displays 'test with \sigma'
uimenu(h,'Label','<html>test with &#0963</html>') % displays 'test with ?', but it works
%                                                   with other uicontrols like popupmenus
uimenu(h,'Label','<html>test with <font face="Symbol">s</font></html>') 
% ^ displays 'test with s', s being with a different font, but not the Symbol one
```

Any idea how this can be achieved? I'm on R2014a.

Note that "µ" (as available on my keyboard, which I just used to type this exact one) works but not "μ" (as in Unicode 03BC, which I just used to type this exact one).

Comment: The first one works in R2016b

Comment: Good point. I just added a comment that I was under R2014a.

Comment: Try to use the (la)tex interpreter.

Comment: @M_Tornack There is no interpreter setting / option for uimenus. That's the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

This one works in R2015b

```
uimenu(h,'Label',['test with ', char(963)])
```